# Argument of type float does not match GLfloat?

Tags: c++, opengl, casting, arguments

im trying to do something here but that error shows up i really have no idea how to get it done right i tried to put all the variables in the Figure.h as GLfloat instead of just float and the same error keeps appearing any idea?
here is my Figure.h

```
Class Figure
{
    public:
        Figure(float x,float y,float z);
        void Parameters(float x,float y,float z);
        void Draw();
        float paramx(){
        return x1;
        }
        float paramy(){
        return y1;
        }
        float paramz(){
        return z1;
        }
    protected:
    private:
    float x1,y1,z1;
    list <Figure> m_vertices;
};
```

and here is my .cpp the one giving me all the trouble >.<

```
Figure::Figure(float x,float y,float z){
this->x1=x;
this->y1=y;
this->z1=z;
}
void Figure::Parameters(float x,float y,float z)
{
m_vertices.push_back(Figure(x, y, z));
}
void Figure::Draw()
{
    list<Figure>::iterator p = m_vertices.begin();
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    while(p != m_vertices.end()){
        glNormal3f(p->paramx,p->paramy,p->paramz);
        glVertex3f(p->paramx,p->paramy,p->paramz);
        p++;
    }
    glEnd();

}
```

Supposedly the problem is at glNormal3f and glVertex3f any help would be REALLY appreciated thank you very much

Comment: Code could be cleaned up a bit... :) It's `class`, not `Class`. What's the point of an empty `protected:` specifier? You probably want a `vector`, as `list` is likely the worse performing container you could choose. (`deque` is good too.) And you should factor out a Point from a Figure, right now a Figure is both a point and collection of points. Use an initialization list in the constructor, and even if you don't drop `this->`; it's redundant and noisy. `Parameters` is a poor name, it doesn't really describe what's going on. And you might as well use a for-loop rather than a while-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* the functions:

```
    glNormal3f(p->paramx(), p->paramy(), p->paramz());
    glVertex3f(p->paramx(), p->paramy(), p->paramz());
```

Answer (score 0):

`list<Figure>::iterator p` ... so `p` is an iterator which means you need to access the underlying data like this `(*p).paramx()`.  But that may not be the whole problem.  If there's no implicit conversion from float to GLfloat then the compiler will still complain.

[EDIT] I stand corrected.  `(*p).paramx()` is the same as `p->paramx()`

Comment: `p->` is the same as `(*p).`.